# Creating a calculated column, and appending it to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, append, apply, pandas-groupby

My dataset (called 'train') is regarding mortgage applications. In order to improve my prediction of 'accepted' (0/1), I am trying to calculate 'lender acceptance ratio', and would like to append that new column to my dataset.

The dataset is 500k rows, lender id varies from 0 to 6508, but not all of the id's (integers) in between actually exist.

I have tried:

Method 1:
Creating a pivot table. This works:

```
train.pivot_table(index=['lender'], aggfunc='mean', values=['accepted'])
```

BUT: I can't seem to append the results of this pivot table to my dataset:

- Not directly, in one line of code.
- Not indirectly, by adding the results of this pivot table to an empty dataframe, and then merging with 'on=lender_id'.

Method 2:
Creating a new column with a groupby function. I used this:

```
train['lender_ar'] = train.groupby('lender').transform('mean')
```

, but am getting:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 21, placement implies 1
```

A bit of my dataset:

```
lender  accepted
4536       1
2458       0
5710       1
5888       1
289        1
```

I hope someone can help! Thanks!

Comment: You're very close, think you need `train['lender_ar'] = train.groupby('lender')['accepted'].transform('mean')`

Comment: Thank you very much, @Chris_A! This works!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use `df.join` as the original dataset and the averages will not have same dimensions.

```
train.join(train.groupby('lender').mean(), on='lender')
```